# Expected Payoffs

Tags: probability-distributions, expectation

In simple setting consider revenue is dependent on variable $w$ which is uniformly distributed $[0,1]$. The revenue function is $wd$, where $d$ is development program. How to I get the expected revenue in such instances where $w$ can take any value from $0$ to $1$ with equal probability.

This might be a simple problem but I am really weak at maths so help will be appreciated.

thanks for the reply. So my actual problem was: 
Principal is interested in buying lake. The revenues of operating the lake as a camping site are determined by the weather (a random parameter $w$ distributed uniformly on $[0, 1]$) and by the development programme $d$. The revenue function is $wd$, the cost of development is $(d^2-1)/2$ and the agent outside option is $x>0$. Principal needs to specify a contract paying the agent an amount $π$ (if the site produces revenue $R$, the principal gets $R-π$ and the agent get $π$). Suppose that the agent have to accept or reject the contract before observing $w$, but choose the development programme after observing it. $π=aR$.

Now if I solve this by your method will it be correct that principal expected payoff will be $d/2-π$ and agent expected payoff will be $ad/2-(d^2-1)/2$

Comment: should agent expected payoff be $$\int_0^1 {[awd]dw-(d^2-1)/2} $$ and principal expected payoff be $$\int_0^1 {[wd-awd]dw} $$

Answer (score 1):

You need to know what is the expected value of the uniformly distributed variable $w$. Let me denote the expected value by $E$, then $E(w)$ is the expected value of $w$, and in fact $E(w) = \frac{1}{2}$. This is perhaps not surprising, as $\frac{1}{2}$ is the midpoint of the interval $[0,1]$.

What you really want is $E(wd)$. However, $d$ is not random, so you can do the calculation as
$$E(wd) = dE(w) = \frac{d}{2}.$$

This is the expected revenue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am confused that if the expected payoff will be like that than agent and principal expected payoff will always be >0 even if the actual value of w=0. where there is equally likelihood of 0 taking place.